# What is correct go build mode for Windows DLL file?

Tags: c, go, gcc, dll, cgo

These two steps:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -o a.exe main.o MyThing.dll
```

Work great to make windows exe that can call methods inside MyThing.dll. Note gcc main.c without the -c would give error like:

`undefined reference to MyThing_method`

But when trying to get this same system working in a Golang program using cgo I get same undefined reference errors like I did with gcc without the -c. I've read:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs

And would love to try and use `syscall.NewLazyDLL` but my issue is my foo.go file is calling C.SomeMethod() and inside that method it makes calls to the methods inside the DLL. So it seems I need a way to

`go build -buildmode=c-share -o MyThing.dll`

But I can't seem to get the right sequence. Am I right that if I can do this in the simple C program, there must be a way to do this from Golang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just getting rid of this extra c file and calling the methods I needed from Go like https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs explains. Works great.